# Any chance to unbrick relocked HTC One M7 with S-on and a old copy of the RUU.zip

Tags: unbricking, fastboot, htc-one, bootloader-lock, ruu

### Background

After 1 year of use,  the most recent OTA to my HTC One rendered several key features,  including the notification bar and the home and back buttons, unusable , effectively soft-bricking my phone. Although it was still under warranty, I decided to fix the matter myself,  and also try a custom ROM. Unfortunately, I was unable to make a backup with ADB,  because that was one of the functions the OTA update rendered unusable.

First,  I tried a few factory resets,  to no avail. I decided more drastic measures were needed and unlocked my bootloader using the instructions at [HTC Dev](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader) and installed a custom recovery, [ClockworkMod Touch](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager).

I then tried to flash a new ROM, the newest snapshot release of [CyanogenMod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=m7&type=snapshot), via ADB sideload. Unfortunately, I was not aware of the need to change the CID,  and thus rendered main ROM completely non-functional. Around this time,  ADB also ceased to function in recovery, and my device was no longer detected.

A week or so later,  I flashed a different recovery, [TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/htconem7gsm.html) and again flashed it with fastboot. This restored ADB functionality, however,  ADB still failed to detect my device in sideload mode, which caused me to be unable to use the Guru Reset tool I managed to download. I then searched for and found a RUU.zip for my CID, VODAP021, at [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one/general/lollipop-ruu-zip-small-collection-t3053944). I then tried to flash it. I re-locked the bootloader and tried to flash it with

```
fastboot flash zip RUU.zip
```

after putting the phone in RUU mode, which returned

```
load_file: could not allocate (filesize) bytes
```

presumably because 1.5 GiB was too much to handle.

### My question

Is there and hope of unbricking my phone (HTC M7_ul) now that I can't access recovery or normal ROM, and have a relocked bootloader with S-On? If so how,  and if not,  what do you suggest I do with it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34264/discussion-on-question-by-alpha3031-any-chance-to-unbrick-relocked-htc-one-m7).